# Do you make an ability check when casting Counterspell at 4th level or higher?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, counterspelling

For *counterspell* at higher levels, the PHB says:

> ***At Higher Levels.*** When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 4th level or higher, the interrupted spell has no effect if its level is less than or equal to the level of the spell slot you used.

If you cast *counterspell* as a 4th-level spell or higher, do you still get to make the ability check if the spell you are trying to counter is higher than the spell level you cast? Or does just nothing happen on a successful save when you cast *counterspell* as 4th level or higher?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you would still need to make an ability check if the spell you're trying to counter is of a higher level than what Counterspell was cast at.

The **At Higher Levels** text only increases the power of the spell as stated. It doesn't "override" the rest of the spell's text or cancel it out in any way.

Comment: Yup, if Bob casts Fireball as a 6th level spell, and Steve counter-spells it at level 5, then it's the same roll as if Steve had cast at 3rd level.  However, if Steve casts at 6th level, then the spell is automatically countered.  No need for a roll.